# SharedPreferences manager class for multiple XMLs files

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I have an application which manages data through SharedPreferences (SP).
I splitted them in different XML files to make the operations faster (clear, commit, apply, ...) and be more organized.
I also created a class for each one to abstract operations and create boilerplate code to avoid duplicating the same code on classes that need to update data on SP.

Since the idea of having a SP is to share information throughout the application, in my case it's better to use the application context to manipulate data on it, even though SP is a single instance.

But I'm not sure if it is a good practice to do this. Have you ever faced a similar situation?

My current implementation (snippet):

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static PreferenceHelper mPref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mPref = new PreferenceHelper(this);
    }
}
```

**PreferenceHelper.java**

```
public class PreferenceHelper {
    private PreferenceUser mPrefUser;
    private PreferenceTechnician mPrefTechnician;

    public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
        this.mPrefUser = new PreferenceUser(context);
        this.mPrefTechnician = new PreferenceTechnician(context);
    }

    public PreferenceUser getPrefUser() {
        return mPrefUser;
    }

    public PreferenceTechnician getPrefTechnician() {
        return mPrefTechnician;
    }
}
```

**PreferenceUser.java**

```
public class PreferenceUser {
    private static final String PREF_USER_FILENAME = "user";
    private SharedPreferences mPref;

    public PreferenceUser(Context context) {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_USER_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mPref.edit().clear().commit();
    }

    public void saveNewUser(User user) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
        editor.putString(user.getId(), gson.toJson(user));
        editor.commit();
    }

    public List<User> getAllList() {
        ...
        // get a map, convert to POJO using Gson,etc
        ...
    }
}
```

**PreferenceTechnician.java**

```
Same as PreferenceUser, but for Techs
```

**MainActivity.java (or any other that needs to read/write from/to SP)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        writeSomethingOnSP();
    }

    private void writeSomethingOnSP() {
         MyApplication.getPref().getPrefUser().saveNewUser(new User(1, "Ana", "Developer"));
    }
}
```

Whenever I need to read or write something on the SharedPreference, I use **MyApplication.getPref().getPrefNameOfPreference().doSomeAction();**.

Can I have your opinion about this approach?

Comment: This world is really small... Mineiro here..  from SIDI :)

Comment: Wow!!! Any problem with SharedPreferences? XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similiar issues and I dediced to fix with `static` methods.

Since `SharedPreferences` are not heavly used, I decided to not store any instance of them but to get them whenever I need them. Also, since all read/write operations are centered in the same class, I have the control that I need (save this setting on that file etc)

I did something like:

```
public class SettingsUtil {

    private static final String PREF_USER_FILENAME = "user";
    private static final String PREF_TECH_FILENAME = "tech";

    public static void saveNewUser(Context context, User user) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_USER_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        ....
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static void addNewTech(Context context, Tech tech) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_TECH_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        ....
        editor.apply();
    }

    ...

}
```

Then, to call:

```
Settings.Util.addNewUser(this, new User(1, "Ana", "Developer"));
```

Not sure if this helps you. I found it simple and it gave the control that I was looking for.

Comment: Hello, Mineiro! It's a great suggestion. In my case is a bit tough to implement your suggestion because the app was architectured to use SP as a storage rather than SQLite. I would have to create many many methods to manage my data. On the other hand I could create one "Util" class for each file. To give you an idea, I have 11 SPs!